# The solution of a set of equations is about to appear but still elusive.

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

A set of equation is derived from an elastic problem with axisymmetry. **The solution is assumed in a serial form, whose coeffecients are almost found but still remain elusive because of the expansion of the non-homogenious term. Could someone help me out?**

The equations about $u(r,z)$ and $w(r)$ are
$$\partial_{rr}u+\frac{\partial_ru}{r}-\frac{u}{r^2}+a^2\partial_{zz}u=0 ……(a)$$
$$\int_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}} (b(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r})(\partial_zu+\partial_rw)-c\nabla^2\nabla^2w)dz=f……(b)$$
where $a,b$ and $c$ are known constant, $f$ is a known function of $r$, $\nabla^2=(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r})\partial_r$ is the 2D Laplacian operator under cylinderical coordinates, and $r\in[0,R], z\in[-\frac{h}{2},\frac{h}{2}]$.

The BCs (1~7) are
$$u(0,z)=0,  u(R,z)=0$$
$$w(R)=0,  \partial_rw(0)=0,  \partial_rw(R)=0$$
$$\partial_zu(r,-\frac{h}{2})+\partial_rw(r)=\partial_zu(r,\frac{h}{2})+\partial_rw(r)=0$$

First, I try to gain knowledge about the probable form of $u(r,z)$ through eq.(a). Combined with the boundary conditions, $u(0,z)=u(R,z)=0$, and the physcial fact that $u(r,z)$ is anti-symmetric with respect to $z$, **eq.(a) is partly solve by saperation of variables**, i.e.
$$u(r,z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}u_k \sinh(\frac{a_k}{a}z) J_1(a_kr) ……(c)$$

where, $u_k$ is the coefficients dependent on $k$ and to be determined, $a_k=j_k^{(1)}/R$.  $J_{\nu}(r)$ is the $\nu$th ordered Bessel function and $j_{k}^{(\nu)}$ is the $k$th zero of $J_{\nu}(r)$.

Besides, ${\{J_0(a_kr)\}}$ for $k=0,1,2,...$ is also a set of complete orthogonal bases in $(0,R)$ with weight $r$ (e.g.,see [this lecture note](https://faculty.fiu.edu/%7Emeziani/Note12.pdf)). Therefore, $w(r)$ **may be represented by**
$$ w(r)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}w_k J_0(a_kr)……(d)  $$
where, $w_k$ is another coefficient to be determined and dependent on $k$.

Plug eq.(d) into the boundary condition that $\partial_ru(r,\frac{h}{2})+\partial_rw(r)=0$, one obtains
$$w_k=0, (k=0)$$and
$$w_k=\frac{u_k}{a}\cosh(\frac{a_kh}{2a}),(k=1,2,3,...)……(e)$$
which suggests that the term $J_0(a_0r)=1$ is **not included** in the expansion of $w(r)$.

Plug eqs.(c~e) into eq.(b), we arrive at
$$f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}u_kp_kJ_0(a_kr)……(f)$$
where $p_k$ is a known parameter dependent on $k$.

So far, seemingly so good. **If we could expand $f$ as a series of $J_0(a_kr)$, the problem would be solved**.

Calculate this expansion, we get
$$ f=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_kJ_0(a_kr)……(g)$$
where $f_k$ is a known coefficients dependent on $k$.

**However, eq.(g) has one extra term at $k=0$ compared with eq.(f), which hinders me and $u_k$ couldn't be finalized especially when $f$ is a constant.**

**It seems to be so close to the solution. Could someone help me out?**

**Any other suggestion on solving the equations would also be appriciated**

Comment: Does eq.(g) emerge because eq.(d) fails to satisfy the b.c. $w(R)=0$ ?

Comment: How to find, say, two set of basis functions for $u(r,z)$ and $w(r)$ that satisfy all the BCs and possess orthogonality, so that I can perform Galerkin process or Ritz process to solve the equations approximately?

Comment: I try to use eq(c)&(d) as the assumed apprximate solution, and perfome Ritz process. $w(R)=0$ and $\partial_zu(r,\frac{h}{2})+\partial_rw(r)=0$ are considered as two additional contraints, which are added into the functional by introducing two Lagrange multipliers. But the integraion of the functional is pretty hard to evaluate.